# ScrollView inside TouchableOpacity

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, jsx

I'm trying to set a horizontal `ScrollView` inside a `TouchableOpacity` component (for necessary reasons). However the `TouchableOpacity` overrides any horizontal scrolling capabilities and executes the `onPress` even for a horizontal touch movement. 
Is there a way to give the `ScrollView` touch event priority over the parent `Touchable`? That way the user can scroll the component and press it. Below is a code snippet similar to what I'm trying to implement.

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={this._onPress}>
    <View>
        ... Some view I want static ...
    </View>
    <ScrollView
        horizontal={true}>
        ... A bunch of components I want scrollable ...
    </ScrollView>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you put the Scrollview below the Touchable? If it is supposed to be possible to send touch event when pressing the scrollView (when only pressing, not scrolling) I don't think it is possible. How can the Touchable know that an on press motion is going to become a scroll or not when first initialized?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. I tried your code and It's work for me.

```
<TouchableOpacity>
  <View>
    <Text>... Some view I want static ...</Text>
  </View>
  <ScrollView horizontal>
    <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}>
      <Text>... A bunch of components I want scrollable ...</Text>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Great! This works just fine

Comment: Yea, it worked to me as well!

Comment: The text above the scrollview will be touchable, but not the scrollview itself. You need a custom panresponder to do that.

Answer (score 0):

@Henning Hall has the correct answer here, but if that fails, you can implement a PanResponder on either component to get the touch event you need.